# using anchor programs in solana mobile stack

Tags: anchor, web3.js, solana-wallet-adapter, program, react-native

I’m i am new to Solana ecosystem and having a problem with SMS. I am trying to use anchor methods inside [example-react-native-app](https://github.com/solana-mobile/mobile-wallet-adapter/tree/main/examples/example-react-native-app) . i am not able to find any documentations on how to interact with anchor programs inside SMS
I used my frontend code and was able to get data from the program but not able to create transactions
I am sure this is not the right and i have to use the transact method but cant find any documentation
[sendQuestion not working ]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Replace those screenshots of code with the text of the code. This ensures that people searching for fragments of code in Google will be able to find your question.